# Не открывается сайт после смены хостинга

Tags: хостинг, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, несколько дней назад я сменил хостинг и у меня не хочет открывать сайт (ошибка 404) в то время как у тех поддержки и у знакомых заходит без проблем. Я пробовал чистить кеш, но безрезультатно. Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

Comment: ipconfig /flushdns